# How is a - (b - c) = c - (b - a) called?

Tags: arithmetic

What is the following property of a subtraction operator called?

$a - (b - c) = c - (b - a)$

Having a name for this property is important for algebraic structures defined with a subtraction operator but no addition operator. And these are important for measures such as temperatures that can be subtracted from each other but not added to each other. Physicists call these *intensive* measures, while statisticians call these intensive variables.

For example, let’s call *ordinal* a type $\mathfrak{O}$ which terms can be subtracted but not added. The best way to define the subtraction operator for this type is:

$- : \mathfrak{O} \times \mathfrak{O} \longrightarrow \mathfrak{O} \\ a - (b - c) = c - (b - a)$

Interestingly, the codomain of the subtraction operator should actually be an extended type called *cardinal* that does support addition, with addition defined as:

$+ : \mathfrak{C} \times \mathfrak{C} \longrightarrow \mathfrak{C} \\ a + b = c \Longleftrightarrow c - a = b$

Therefore, the codomain of the subtraction operator should be $\mathfrak{O}$, not $\mathfrak{C}$.

$- : \mathfrak{O} \times \mathfrak{O} \longrightarrow \mathfrak{C}$

But, when the domain of the subtraction operator is $\mathfrak{O} \times \mathfrak{C}$, then its codomain remains $\mathfrak{O}$. In other words, you can subtract a temperature from a temperature, and this gives you a temperature delta. But you can also subtract a temperature delta from a temperature, and this gives you a temperature.

From there, it becomes obvious that you can add a temperature delta to a temperature, which gives you a temperature, while adding two temperature deltas to each other gives a temperature delta. In other words, there is no commutative addition operator for the ordinal type $\mathfrak{O}$, but there is something that comes pretty close (hence the confusion for most people).

If you define the ordinal type $\mathfrak{O}$ as a coinductive type with *successor* as coinductive operator, an equivalence relation, and a total order relation, you can define a pair of *forward* and *backward* operators once you have added the subtraction operator and the cardinal type $\mathfrak{C}$, with $\mathfrak{O} \times \mathfrak{C}$ as domain and $\mathfrak{O}$ as codomain.

The *forward* operator is equivalent to performing multiple *successor* operations, while the *backward* operator is equivalent to performing multiple *predecessor* operations. And with these, you have operators that let you “add” and “subtract” temperature deltas to and from temperatures, without letting you add two temperatures together.

This line of thinking has some interesting consequences. For example, it suggests a different definition for the arithmetic mean. Indeed, if one defines the arithmetic mean as a sum divided by a count, how does one gets the average of two temperatures since they cannot be summed?

In order to work around this problem, one has to define the *subdivision* operator on an extension of the cardinal type $\mathfrak{C}$. We will call it the fractional type $\mathfrak{F}$. From there, the arithmetic mean of two ordinal terms (like two temperatures) is defined as:

$a, b : \mathfrak{C} \mid a < b \\ mean(a, b) = forward(a, (b - a) / 2)$

I should also mention that all this should apply to both sets or types, but I do all my work with types instead of sets, just because non-mathematicians are more comfortable with them, and because it lends itself nicely to the approach of building a hierarchy of type whereby an extended type is defined from a primitive type by simply adding an extra relation or operation.

I do not know how far this could go, but I am putting my ideas together on this [notebook](https://beta.observablehq.com/d/06f04aa3a14cdbbd).

Comment: This is a composition of properties (conmutative and associative)

Comment: Why would it have a name?

Comment: I have clarified the original question.

Comment: Even if you only have *interval* variables, you have a category error. Take "time" for instance. You can take the difference between two clock *times*, which gives you a *duration*. A duration is not a time. You can add a duration to a time and get another time. Adding two times is nonsensical. A time doesn't even have a well-defined unit of measure.

Comment: @obscurans You are absolutely correct! The type of the subtraction’s codomain is usually different from the type of its domain. In fact, I would go as far as saying that the codomain’s type is usually an extension of the domain’s type (as in, a type defined with more operators and/or relations).

Comment: In the context of affine geometry, the difference of two points in an affine space is a vector in the underlying vector space. In the context of electricity voltage is determined by a difference in electrical potential. In both these cases, however, you can't take take the difference of two elements and **then** take the difference of **that** with a third element. That is, $(a-b)-c$ makes no sense in these contexts.

Comment: You can, however, define $a-(b-c)$ which is equal to $c-(b-a)$, which is the equivalent form of $a+(b-c)=b+(a-c)$. The two operations that *are* defined are 1. subtraction of two points, forming a vector, and 2. adding a vector to a point, getting another point. Vectors have a zero so they can be scaled by $-1$.

Comment: @obscurans Good point. In affine geometry if $\,a-(b-c)=d\,$ and $\,a,b,c\,$ are three vertices of a prallelogram, in circular order, then the fourth vertex is $\,d.\,$

Comment: All good points. I am indeed taking inspiration from affine geometry to create my algebraic structures, but quite a few terms are missing for identities like this one in order to write things in a concise and explicit manner.

Comment: How exactly do you define $-$ without defining $+$ first?

Comment: @Somos Excellent point! a - (b - c) = c - (b - a) is the right way to think about it.

Comment: @YiFan Here is how we do it: https://beta.observablehq.com/d/06f04aa3a14cdbbd

Comment: Since nothing I've written here seems to have helped you, I've deleted it. Good luck!

Comment: You remind me of a young man at Trinity.

Answer (score 0):

By definition $$ (a-b)-c = (a-b)+(-c) = (a+(-b))+(-c)$$

Now we apply the associative property of addition to get

$$ ((a+(-b))+(-c) = a+((-b)+(-c))$$

Now we use the commutative and associative  properties of addition to get $$ a+((-b)+(-c))= a+((-c)+(-b)) =(a+(-c))+(-b)=(a-c)-b$$

Comment: I should have clarified the fact that my working set or type does not have any addition, sorry.

Comment: @ismael really? Then what does `a - (0 - b)` (where 0 = c - c) do?

Comment: @JohnDvorak I have updated the original post. This should help.

Answer (score 0):

You may assume $a,b,c \in G$ where $\left< G, + \right>$ is an abelian group.

$(a-b) - c $

$= (a + (-b ) ) + ( - c ) $ ($(-b),(-c)$ is the inverse for $b,c$, repectively)

$= a + ( (-b) + (-c) )$ (associativity)

$= a + ( (-c) + (-b) )$ (commutativity)

$= ( a + (-c) ) + (-b)$ (associativity)

$= ( a-c ) - b$

Comment: I should have clarified the fact that my working set or type does not have any addition, sorry.